# Requests and discussion about the shop

Tags: discussion, shop

Is Meta Stack Overflow the right place to discuss the [Stack Exchange Shop](http://shop.stackexchange.com/)? It would seem overkill that it needs its own meta but to quote the opening line of [this meta's About page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about):

> This site is for meta-discussion of
>   the Stack Exchange family of Q&A
>   websites.

Anyway, is this where you would make requests (or suggest ideas, etc.) for merchandise for the shop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is the right place. Anything generic-SE is handled here. The correct tag for store discussions (at least for now), BTW, is [shop](/questions/tagged/shop).

Comment: I thought store/shop were tag synonyms...should they be?